# I am not able to prefill mobile number in paypal payment integration

Tags: python, paypal

```
payment = Payment({
    "intent": "sale",

    "application_context": {
        "locale": "en_IN",
        "user_action": "commit",
        "shipping_preference": "NO_SHIPPING",
        "landing_page": "billing"
    },

    # Set payment method
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal",
        "payer_info": {
            "email": email,
            "first_name": first_name,
            "last_name": last_name,
            "shipping_address": {
            "phone": phone,
            }
        }
    },

    # Set redirect URLs
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "example.com/confpayment/",
        "cancel_url": "examplecom/payment_fail/"
    },
    # Set transaction object
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "total": str(amount),
            # "total": "1",
            "currency": "INR"
        },
        "description": "payment description"
    }]
})
```

I am getting **Incoming JSON request does not map to API request**

> Error:`{'name': 'MALFORMED_REQUEST', 'message': 'Incoming JSON request does not map to API request', 'information_link': 'https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST', 'debug_id': '51397a89429bd'}`

All other things are prefilled except for mobile number.
Please help me out on this.

I am not sure whether the API format is correct or not.

Comment: Now I am geting this "This field currently not supported in this request"

Answer (score 0):

Edit preview code is wrong :

Documentation of the `payer` property here (link corrected to V2) :

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/?mark=payer#definition-payer

Error, remove the extra comma at : `"phone": "",`

```
"payer_info": {
...
    "shipping_address": {
        "phone": ""
    }
 }
```

THIS CODE SEEMS TO BE WRONG :

Move the `phone` outside the `shipping_address` :

```
"payer_info": {
...
    "shipping_address": {
    ...
    },
    "phone": ""
 }
```

Full samples here : http://www.seneca-re.com/wp-content/plugins/estatik/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/payments/ListPayments.php

Comment: Now I am geting this "This field currently not supported in this request"

Comment: Check the API you use, it seems avalaible on API V2 not on V1 : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/   => Orders / Phone

Comment: Couldn't find anything useful here for phone number field

Comment: Actually the position of this field in the JSON format is the main concern thats why I am getting this error.

Comment: Have you try your code by removing the extra comma => "phone": phone not "phone": phone,

Comment: This time no error came but still phone number field was blank, any other thoughts on this?

Comment: No idea for this, check your json and the format of the string you pass. The phone number, in E.123 format. Maximum length is 50 characters. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v1/?mark=payer#definition-shipping_address

Comment: I did it now by moving shipping_address to transaction payload and we need to prefill address as well.

Comment: Sorry for that : check the version of the API on the url and example you find on the net. The right link for explanation is : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/?mark=payer#definition-shipping_detail => check you have V2 not V1 on the links.

Comment: I assume your calls are something like : /v2/checkout/orders not /v1/checkout/orders so take particular attention of the version on the examples or documentation you find, I think it is a common mistake.

Comment: Yes there is some issue with different version, anyway I did it now by moving shipping_address to transaction payload and we need to prefill address as well